# Finding Equations for Common Tangents Between Two Ellipses, A General Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

I'm interested in finding the four common tangents between two ellipses. While I've found some fascinating approaches using dual conics to identify their intersection points ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65554671/704168), [link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267839/general-equations-for-common-tangents-to-two-ellipses?noredirect=1&lq=1)), my primary objective is to obtain the tangent equations in the original Cartesian coordinate system.

The methods I've come across seem to work within the realm of projective geometry, which is beyond my current mathematical expertise. Any help in simplifying this to Cartesian coordinates would be invaluable.

##### My Current Understanding

Let's say we have two ellipses defined by their canonical matrices `E1` and `E2`.

1. **Dual Conics**: The common tangents can be found at the intersection points of the dual conics `C1 = E1^-1` and `C2 = E2^-1`.
2. **Intersection Points**: To find these, we consider the pencil of conics `C1 - t * C2` (where `t` is real) and solve for `t` in `det(C1 - t * C2) = 0`. Since this is a cubic equation, it yields up to three roots `t0`, `t1`, and `t2`, which correspond to up to three degenerate conics—usually intersecting lines. The equation for these degenerate conics is `C1 - t_i * C2 = 0`.
3. **Coordinates of Intersection Points**: As these points lie on the conics, for each `t_i` we should have:

   ```
   (C1 - t_i * C2) * X_i = 0
   ```

   Subsequently:

   ```
   ((C2^-1 * C1) - t_i * I) * X_i = 0
   ```

Based on an answer by @Futurologist [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65554671/704168), this is an eigenvalue equation, with `t_i` as the eigenvalue and `X_i` as the eigenvector. Therefore, `X_i` should give me the coordinates of the intersection points, which should also provide the coefficients for the tangents in Cartesian coordinates.

Have I understood this correctly, or is there something I'm missing?

**Example**
Let's have a concrete example with the 2 ellipsis:

`E1: 36 * x^2 + 9 * y^2 - 324 = 0`

and

`E2: 4 * x^2 + y^2  - 56 * x - 6 * y + 201 = 0`

Considering the method I described above, please can you explain how you get the four tangents final equations?

Comment: How are your ellipses given?

Comment: @trula I've added more details to my question

Comment: Maybe not what you're looking for but here's a treatment by an old master: [Salmon, Conic Sections, pg 344 Article 378](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonconics00salm_0/page/344/mode/2up?view=theater)

Comment: Note that there are possible from 4 to none such tangents.

Comment: A real affine ellipse is the zero-set of $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-1.$ All ellipses are generated from these ones by rotation and translation or is the zero-set of $$\text{Constant}\cdot(\frac{(\cos{\theta_i}(x-h_i)+\sin{\theta_i}(y-k_i))^2}{a^2}+\frac{(-\sin{\theta_i}(x-h_i)+\cos{\theta_i}(y-k_i))^2}{b^2}-1), i=1,2$$

Comment: The duals in coordinates $(X,Y)$ in any concrete example are easily calculated, and the $0$ to $4$ intersection points $(X_i,Y_i)$ give the lines $X_ix+Y_iy+1=0.$

Comment: Ok @Jan-MagnusØkland let's have a concrete example with the 2 ellipsis:
`E0: 36.0 * x^2 + -0.0 * x * y + 9.0 * y^2  + 0.0 * x + 0.0 * y + -324.0 = 0` 
and
`E1: 4.0 * x^2 + -0.0 * x * y + 1.0 * y^2  + -56.0 * x + -6.0 * y + 201.0 = 0`

Considering the method I described in my question, please can you explain how you get the four tangents final equations. Super thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: complex numbers**

This implementation with complex numbers seems to work for now

```
import math
import cmath
import numpy as np

'''
Algorithm for finding the coefficients of 
the linear equations of the four tangent 
lines of a pair of non-intersecting ellipses
'''

# given a pair of conics, as a pair of symmetric matrices, 
# calculate the vector k = (k[0], k[1], k[2]) of values for each of which 
# the conic c1 - k[i]*c2 from the pencil of conics c1 - t*c2 
# is a degenerate conic (the anti-symmetric product of a pair of linear forms) 
# and also find the matrix U 
# of the projective transformation that simplifies the geometry of 
# the pair of conics, and the geometry of the pencil c1 - t*c2 in general, 
# as well as the geometry of the three degenerate conics in particular

def get_transformation(c1, c2):
    '''
    c1 and c2 are 3 by 3 symmetric matrices of the two conics
    '''
    c21 = np.linalg.inv(c2).dot(c1)
    k, U = np.linalg.eig(c21)
    return k, U

def find_common_points(c1, c2):
    k, U = get_transformation(c1, c2)
    L1 = (U.T).dot((c1 - k[0]*c2).dot(U))
    L2 = (U.T).dot((c1 - k[1]*c2).dot(U))
    x_0 = cmath.sqrt(-(L2[2,2] / L2[0,0]))
    y_0 = cmath.sqrt(-(L1[2,2] / L1[1,1]))
    sol = np.array([[ x_0,  y_0, 1], 
                    [-x_0, -y_0, 1],
                    [-x_0,  y_0, 1],
                    [ x_0, -y_0, 1]])
    sol = sol.dot(U.T)
    return sol

# combination of the algorithms form above with the 
# transformation of the problem of common tangents of the two ellipses
# to its dual - the intersection points of the two dual ellipses 
# The intersection points of the dual ellipses
# are the common tangents of the two original ellipses

def find_common_tangents(c1, c2):
    dc1 = np.linalg.inv(c1)
    dc2 = np.linalg.inv(c2)
    return find_common_points(dc1, dc2)
```

**Previous version: real version, non-intersecting ellipses**

If an algorithm is what you are seeking, here is one, based on my previous posts you cited:

```
import math
import numpy as np

'''
Algorithm for finding the coefficients of 
the linear equations of the four tangent 
lines of a pair of non-intersecting ellipses
'''

# given a pair of conics, as a pair of symmetric matrices, 
# calculate the vector k = (k[0], k[1], k[2]) of values for each of which 
# the conic c1 - k[i]*c2 from the pencil of conics c1 - t*c2 
# is a degenerate conic (the anti-symmetric product of a pair of linear forms) 
# and also find the matrix U 
# of the projective transformation that simplifies the geometry of 
# the pair of conics, and the geometry of the pencil c1 - t*c2 in general, 
# as well as the geometry of the three degenerate conics in particular
   
def get_transformation(c1, c2):
    '''
    c1 and c2 are 3 by 3 symmetric matrices of the two conics
    '''
    c21 = np.linalg.inv(c2).dot(c1)
    k, U = np.linalg.eig(c21)
    return k, U


# find the common points, i.e. points of intersection, 
# of a pair of non-intersecting ellipses
# represented by a pair of symmetric matrices

def find_common_points(c1, c2):
    '''
    c1 and c2 are 3 by 3 symmetric matrices of the two conics
    '''
    k, U = get_transformation(c1, c2)
    L1 = (U.T).dot((c1 - k[0]*c2).dot(U))
    L2 = (U.T).dot((c1 - k[1]*c2).dot(U))
    sol = np.ones((4,3), dtype=float)
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            sol[i+2*j,0:2] = np.array([math.sqrt(abs(L2[2,2] / L2[0,0]))*(-1)**i, math.sqrt(abs(L1[2,2] / L1[1,1]))*(-1)**j])
    sol = sol.dot(U.T)
    return sol

# combination of the algorithms form above with the 
# transformation of the problem of common tangents of the two ellipses
# to its dual - the intersection points of the two dual ellipses 
# The intersection points of the dual ellipses
# are the common tangents of the two original ellipses

def find_common_tangents(c1, c2):
    dc1 = np.linalg.inv(c1)
    dc2 = np.linalg.inv(c2)
    return find_common_points(dc1, dc2)
```

I tested it with one example, and it worked, but have not run more tests.
Here is a test script:

```
'''
Begin generation of test conics
'''

def cos_sin(angle_deg):
    return math.cos(angle_deg*math.pi/180), math.sin(angle_deg*math.pi/180)

def rotation(cs_sn):
    return np.array([[cs_sn[0], -cs_sn[1]], 
                     [cs_sn[1],  cs_sn[0]]])

def isom(angle, translation):
    '''
    #isometry from conic-aligned coordinate system (conic attached)
    #to global coordinate system (world system) 
    isometry from global coordinate system (world system) 
    to conic-aligned coordinate system (conic attached) 
    '''
    cos_, sin_ = cos_sin(-angle)
    tr = - rotation((cos_, sin_)).dot(translation)
    return np.array([[ cos_, -sin_, tr[0]], 
                     [ sin_,  cos_, tr[1]], 
                     [    0,     0,    1 ]])

def conic(major, minor, angle, center):
    D = np.array([[minor**2,        0,                 0],
                  [       0, major**2,                 0], 
                  [       0,        0, -(minor*major)**2]])
    U = isom(angle, center)
    return (U.T).dot(D.dot(U)) 

def conic_coeff(c):
    return np.array( (c[0,0], 2*c[0,1], c[1,1], 2*c[0,2], 2*c[1,2], c[2,2]) )

'''End generation of test conics'''


# BEGIN test:

rnd=5 # rounding to 5 digits after the decimal point. Choose as you like.

a = 2
b = 1
cntr = np.array([0,0])
w = 45

C1 = conic(a, b, w, cntr)
Eq1 = conic_coeff(C1).round(rnd)

a = 3
b = 1
cntr = np.array([7,0])
w = 120

C2 = conic(a, b, w, cntr)
Eq2 = conic_coeff(C2).round(rnd)

common_tangents = find_common_tangents(C1, C2)

print()
print('equation of the conic 1:')
print(f'{Eq1[0]}x**2 + {Eq1[1]}xy + {Eq1[2]}y**2 + {Eq1[3]}x + {Eq1[4]}y + {Eq1[5]} = 0')
print()
print('equation of conic 2:')
print(f'{Eq2[0]}x**2 + {Eq2[1]}xy + {Eq2[2]}y**2 + {Eq2[3]}x + {Eq2[4]}y + {Eq2[5]} = 0')
print()

print('The coefficients of the linear equations of the four tangent lines to the conics 1 and 2 are: ')
print(common_tangents.round(rnd))
```

After running this particular test, I got as output:

```
equation of conic 1:
2.5x**2 + -3.0xy + 2.5y**2 + 0.0x + 0.0y + -4.0 = 0

equation of conic 2:
7.0x**2 + 6.9282xy + 3.0y**2 + -98.0x + -48.49742y + 334.0 = 0

the coefficients of the linear equations of the four tangent lines to the conics 1 and 2 are: 
[[ 0.52106  0.85509 -1.96045]
 [ 0.07325  0.63866  1.08326]
 [-0.274    1.24082 -1.73691]
 [-0.72181  1.02439  1.3068 ]]
```

Then I went to [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), because I find it convenient, and plotted the output, just to check visually:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! You're a boss! One extra question: is there a simple way to pick only external tangents?

Comment: And a second question: what about the cases when the 2 initial ellipses are intersecting. The script doesn't seem to find the right tangents

Comment: @MohG 1) There is a way to find the inner common tangents but it requires some work: e.g. the centres of the ellipses should be on opposite sides of a common tangent. But your post started with: "[I am] interested in finding the four common tangents between two ellipses" 2) If the two ellipses intersect, then you have to modify the algorithm to work with complex numbers.

Comment: @MohG In your OP you state: "Therefore, X_i should give me the coordinates of the intersection points, which should also provide the coefficients for the tangents in Cartesian coordinates." This is not true. The three eigenvectors X_i are the columns of the orthogonal matrix U, which is the projective transformation that transforms the two ellipses from general configuration into a special configuration in which the solutions to the problem are very easy to find. Then, one uses U to transform back the solutions of the special configuration into the solutions of the general configuration.

Comment: Got it @Futurologist, thank you. As for intersecting ellipses, please could you tell more about how to modify the algorithm?

Comment: @MohG Maybe check the availability of python packages that uses complex arithmetic and check if numpy works with such complex numbers? If numpy does not work with complex numbers, then check if there is an alternative of numpy that does that.

Comment: @MohG I added an update. Checked it only with the current test. Haven't tested it more than that.

Comment: Awesome @Futurologist! Just tested on a couple of Ellipsis and it works perfectly! Thank you so much for your contribution.

Comment: Hey @Futurologist! Just a last question: in case of intersecting ellipses, I can't find a reliable way to  get the outer tangents. I tried the solution you've described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4026148/1236220) but it doesn't work when we deal with complex numbers.

Comment: @MohG I do not understand what you mean. You have to provide the test cases where the issues you describe come up. That can help in identifying any bugs in the code. Also, I do not know why are still going back to that other post when I already wrote code for your case, including the complex number situation.

Comment: I’m talking about a way to discriminate the inner and the outer tangents among the four ones we get from your code. In particular when ellipses are intersecting. In your [old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4026148/1236220), you've described a nice solution to get the inner tangents, but it doesn't work here for intersecting ellipses. That's why I mentionned it.

Comment: @MohG It doesn't work for intersecting ellipses, because intersecting ellipses do not have inner tangents. Only outer tangents. If the ellipses intersect in two (real) points, there are only two real tangents (the other two are complex) and they are outer. When the ellipses intersect in four (real) points, then there are four real tangents and they are all outer.

Comment: Got it, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You propose E0: $324\cdot(x^2/3^2+y^2/6^2-1) =0$ and E1: $4\cdot((x-7)^2+(y-3)^2/2^2-1)=0$ which have duals, dropping the constants $324$ and $4$; $3^2X^2+6^2Y^2-1=0$ (the ones centered on the origin are particularly easy) and $12X^2+\frac{21}2 XY+\frac54 Y^2+\frac72 X+\frac32 Y+\frac14=0.$ The matrix of the second ellipse is $M=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-7\\0&\frac14&-\frac34\\-7&-\frac34&\frac{201}4\end{pmatrix}$ and that has inverse $\frac1{\det M}\begin{pmatrix}12&\frac{21}4&\frac74\\\frac{21}4&\frac54&\frac34\\\frac74&\frac34&\frac14\end{pmatrix}.$ The ideal of the two duals has primary decomposition $\langle 21X+9Y+2,205Y^2+4Y-5\rangle \cap  \langle 21X+9Y+4,615Y^2+24Y-11\rangle$ so they intersect in $(X,Y)=$ $$(-\frac{9\sqrt3\sqrt7+56}{615},\frac{7\sqrt3\sqrt7-2}{205}), (\frac{9\sqrt3\sqrt7-56}{615}, -\frac{7\sqrt3\sqrt7+2}{205}),\\(-\frac{3\sqrt3\sqrt{47}+112}{615}, \frac{7 \sqrt3 \sqrt{47}-12}{615}),(\frac{3 \sqrt3\sqrt{47}-112}{615}, -\frac{7\sqrt3\sqrt{47}+12}{615}),$$ or $$(-0.1581189939099228,0.1467220969009311),\\(-0.02399482722828852,-0.1662342920228823),\\ (-0.2400374410749817,0.1156429180638462), \\(-0.124190201201441,-0.1546673083077486),$$ see [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/mmjyqjar), making the four common tangents $$-\frac{9\sqrt3\sqrt7+56}{615}x+\frac{7\sqrt3\sqrt7-2}{205}y+1=0, \frac{9\sqrt3\sqrt7-56}{615}x -\frac{7\sqrt3\sqrt7+2}{205}y+1=0\\-\frac{3\sqrt3\sqrt{47}+112}{615}x +\frac{7 \sqrt3 \sqrt{47}-12}{615}y+1=0,\frac{3 \sqrt3\sqrt{47}-112}{615}x -\frac{7\sqrt3\sqrt{47}+12}{615}y+1=0$$ or $$-0.1581189939099228x+0.1467220969009311y+1=0,\\-0.02399482722828852x-0.1662342920228823y+1=0,\\ -0.2400374410749817x+0.1156429180638462y+1=0, \\-0.124190201201441x-0.1546673083077486y+1=0.$$

[image: The four common tangents]

The affine geometry is in the projective one you've seen in other posts as $z=1$ and dually $Z=1,$ the universal line then goes from being $Xx+Yx+Zz=0$ to $Xx+Yx+1=0.$

**Edit**

If one ellipse is in standard form $$\frac{x^2}{a_1^2}+\frac{y^2}{b_1^2}-1=0,$$ which you can achieve by rotating and translating the plane, landing one in standard form and the other in general form  $$\frac{(\cos{\alpha}(x-h)+\sin{\alpha}(y-k))^2}{a_2^2}+\frac{(-\sin{\alpha}(x-h)+\cos{\alpha}(y-k))^2}{b_2^2}-1=0.$$ Solving this system, I proceed by producing a Lex grobner basis: the first two elements of which are given below. The first is a quartic in $y:$ $q_4(y)=0$ and the next is of the form $Cx+p_3(y)=0.$ Solving the quartic you get one $x$-value for each real root of $q_4(y)=0.$ But there's no way in general around solving a quartic equation for this problem.

```
(a1^4*a2^4*sin(α)^4-2*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*sin(α)^4+a2^4*b1^4*sin(α)^4-2*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*sin(α)^4+4*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*sin(α)^4-2*a2^2*b1^4*b2^2*sin(α)^4+a1^4*b2^4*sin(α)^4-2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^4*sin(α)^4+b1^4*b2^4*sin(α)^4-8*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h*k*cos(α)*sin(α)+8*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*k*cos(α)*sin(α)+2*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*sin(α)^2-2*a2^4*b1^4*sin(α)^2+2*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*sin(α)^2-4*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*sin(α)^2+2*a2^2*b1^4*b2^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^4*b2^4*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^4*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h^2*sin(α)^2+2*a2^2*b1^4*h^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^2*sin(α)^2-2*b1^4*b2^2*h^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^4*a2^2*k^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*k^2*sin(α)^2+2*a1^4*b2^2*k^2*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*k^2*sin(α)^2+a2^4*b1^4-2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2+a1^4*b2^4-2*a2^2*b1^4*h^2+2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^2+b1^4*h^4+2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*k^2-2*a1^4*b2^2*k^2+2*a1^2*b1^2*h^2*k^2+a1^4*k^4)*y^4+(-8*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h*cos(α)*sin(α)+8*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*cos(α)*sin(α)-4*a1^4*a2^2*k*sin(α)^2-4*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*k*sin(α)^2+4*a1^4*b2^2*k*sin(α)^2+4*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*k*sin(α)^2+4*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*k-4*a1^4*b2^2*k+4*a1^2*b1^2*h^2*k+4*a1^4*k^3)*y^3+(2*a1^2*a2^4*sin(α)^4-2*a2^4*b1^2*sin(α)^4-4*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*sin(α)^4+4*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*sin(α)^4+2*a1^2*b2^4*sin(α)^4-2*b1^2*b2^4*sin(α)^4+8*a1^2*a2^2*h*k*cos(α)*sin(α)-8*a1^2*b2^2*h*k*cos(α)*sin(α)-2*a1^4*a2^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*a2^4*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*sin(α)^2+4*a2^4*b1^2*sin(α)^2+2*a1^4*b2^2*sin(α)^2+4*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*sin(α)^2-4*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*b2^4*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*a2^2*h^2*sin(α)^2-4*a2^2*b1^2*h^2*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*b2^2*h^2*sin(α)^2+4*b1^2*b2^2*h^2*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*a2^2*k^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*b2^2*k^2*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2-2*a2^4*b1^2-2*a1^4*b2^2+2*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2+2*a1^2*b1^2*h^2+4*a2^2*b1^2*h^2-2*a1^2*b2^2*h^2-2*b1^2*h^4+6*a1^4*k^2-2*a1^2*a2^2*k^2-2*a1^2*h^2*k^2)*y^2+(8*a1^2*a2^2*h*cos(α)*sin(α)-8*a1^2*b2^2*h*cos(α)*sin(α)+4*a1^2*a2^2*k*sin(α)^2-4*a1^2*b2^2*k*sin(α)^2+4*a1^4*k-4*a1^2*a2^2*k-4*a1^2*h^2*k)*y+a2^4*sin(α)^4-2*a2^2*b2^2*sin(α)^4+b2^4*sin(α)^4+2*a1^2*a2^2*sin(α)^2-2*a2^4*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*b2^2*sin(α)^2+2*a2^2*b2^2*sin(α)^2+2*a2^2*h^2*sin(α)^2-2*b2^2*h^2*sin(α)^2+a1^4-2*a1^2*a2^2+a2^4-2*a1^2*h^2-2*a2^2*h^2+h^4=0

(2*a1^2*a2^6*sin(α)^6-6*a1^2*a2^4*b2^2*sin(α)^6+6*a1^2*a2^2*b2^4*sin(α)^6-2*a1^2*b2^6*sin(α)^6+4*a1^2*a2^4*h*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-8*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+4*a1^2*b2^4*h*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+2*a1^4*a2^4*sin(α)^4-4*a1^2*a2^6*sin(α)^4-4*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*sin(α)^4+10*a1^2*a2^4*b2^2*sin(α)^4+2*a1^4*b2^4*sin(α)^4-8*a1^2*a2^2*b2^4*sin(α)^4+2*a1^2*b2^6*sin(α)^4+2*a1^2*a2^4*h^2*sin(α)^4-4*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h^2*sin(α)^4+2*a1^2*b2^4*h^2*sin(α)^4-4*a1^2*a2^4*h*k*cos(α)*sin(α)+4*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h*k*cos(α)*sin(α)+4*a1^2*a2^2*h^3*k*cos(α)*sin(α)-4*a1^2*b2^2*h^3*k*cos(α)*sin(α)-2*a1^4*a2^4*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*a2^6*sin(α)^2+4*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*sin(α)^2-4*a1^2*a2^4*b2^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^4*b2^4*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*a2^2*b2^4*sin(α)^2+2*a1^4*a2^2*h^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*a2^4*h^2*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^4*b2^2*h^2*sin(α)^2+4*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*b2^4*h^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*a2^2*h^2*k^2*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*b2^2*h^2*k^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h^2+2*a1^4*b2^2*h^2+2*a1^2*b1^2*h^4+2*a1^2*a2^2*h^2*k^2-2*a1^2*h^4*k^2)*x+(-a1^4*a2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)^5+2*a1^2*a2^6*b1^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^5-a2^6*b1^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^5+3*a1^4*a2^4*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^5-6*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^5+3*a2^4*b1^4*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^5-3*a1^4*a2^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^5+6*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^5-3*a2^2*b1^4*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^5+a1^4*b2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)^5-2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)^5+b1^4*b2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)^5-2*a1^2*a2^6*b1^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+2*a2^6*b1^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*a1^4*a2^4*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+6*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-4*a2^4*b1^4*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+4*a1^4*a2^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-6*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+2*a2^2*b1^4*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*a1^4*b2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*a2^4*b1^4*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+4*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+4*a2^2*b1^4*b2^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^4*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*b1^4*b2^4*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+2*a1^4*a2^4*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+2*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-4*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-4*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+2*a1^4*b2^4*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^4*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+a1^4*a2^4*h*k*sin(α)^4-10*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*h*k*sin(α)^4+a2^4*b1^4*h*k*sin(α)^4-2*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^4+20*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^4-2*a2^2*b1^4*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^4+a1^4*b2^4*h*k*sin(α)^4-10*a1^2*b1^2*b2^4*h*k*sin(α)^4+b1^4*b2^4*h*k*sin(α)^4-a2^6*b1^4*cos(α)*sin(α)+2*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+a2^4*b1^4*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-a1^4*a2^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)-2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)+a1^4*b2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)+2*a2^4*b1^4*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-2*a2^2*b1^4*b2^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^4*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-a2^2*b1^4*h^4*cos(α)*sin(α)+b1^4*b2^2*h^4*cos(α)*sin(α)-2*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+2*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-2*a1^4*b2^4*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-10*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+10*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-a1^4*a2^2*k^4*cos(α)*sin(α)+a1^4*b2^2*k^4*cos(α)*sin(α)+10*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*h*k*sin(α)^2-2*a2^4*b1^4*h*k*sin(α)^2+2*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^2-20*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^2+2*a2^2*b1^4*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^2-2*a1^4*b2^4*h*k*sin(α)^2+10*a1^2*b1^2*b2^4*h*k*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h^3*k*sin(α)^2+2*a2^2*b1^4*h^3*k*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^3*k*sin(α)^2-2*b1^4*b2^2*h^3*k*sin(α)^2-2*a1^4*a2^2*h*k^3*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h*k^3*sin(α)^2+2*a1^4*b2^2*h*k^3*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*k^3*sin(α)^2+a2^4*b1^4*h*k-2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*k+a1^4*b2^4*h*k-2*a2^2*b1^4*h^3*k+2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^3*k+b1^4*h^5*k+2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h*k^3-2*a1^4*b2^2*h*k^3+2*a1^2*b1^2*h^3*k^3+a1^4*h*k^5)*y^3+(4*a1^4*a2^4*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+4*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-8*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-8*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+4*a1^4*b2^4*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+4*a1^2*b1^2*b2^4*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-a1^4*a2^4*h*sin(α)^4-6*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*h*sin(α)^4-a2^4*b1^4*h*sin(α)^4+2*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*h*sin(α)^4+12*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*sin(α)^4+2*a2^2*b1^4*b2^2*h*sin(α)^4-a1^4*b2^4*h*sin(α)^4-6*a1^2*b1^2*b2^4*h*sin(α)^4-b1^4*b2^4*h*sin(α)^4-4*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)+4*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)+4*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)-4*a1^4*b2^4*k*cos(α)*sin(α)-4*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)+4*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)-4*a1^4*a2^2*k^3*cos(α)*sin(α)+4*a1^4*b2^2*k^3*cos(α)*sin(α)+6*a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*h*sin(α)^2+2*a2^4*b1^4*h*sin(α)^2-2*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*h*sin(α)^2-12*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*sin(α)^2-2*a2^2*b1^4*b2^2*h*sin(α)^2+2*a1^4*b2^4*h*sin(α)^2+6*a1^2*b1^2*b2^4*h*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h^3*sin(α)^2-2*a2^2*b1^4*h^3*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^3*sin(α)^2+2*b1^4*b2^2*h^3*sin(α)^2-2*a1^4*a2^2*h*k^2*sin(α)^2-2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h*k^2*sin(α)^2+2*a1^4*b2^2*h*k^2*sin(α)^2+2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*k^2*sin(α)^2-a2^4*b1^4*h+2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h-a1^4*b2^4*h+2*a2^2*b1^4*h^3-2*a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^3-b1^4*h^5+2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h*k^2-2*a1^4*b2^2*h*k^2+2*a1^2*b1^2*h^3*k^2+3*a1^4*h*k^4)*y^2+(-3*a1^2*a2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)^5+a2^6*b1^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^5+9*a1^2*a2^4*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^5-3*a2^4*b1^2*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^5-9*a1^2*a2^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^5+3*a2^2*b1^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^5+3*a1^2*b2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)^5-b1^2*b2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)^5+a1^4*a2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+3*a1^2*a2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*a2^6*b1^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-9*a1^2*a2^4*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+4*a2^4*b1^2*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+a1^4*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+9*a1^2*a2^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+a1^2*b1^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-3*a1^2*b2^6*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+a1^2*a2^4*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+2*a2^4*b1^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-4*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+a1^2*b2^4*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+2*b1^2*b2^4*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-a1^2*a2^4*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+2*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-a1^2*b2^4*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+11*a1^2*a2^4*h*k*sin(α)^4-a2^4*b1^2*h*k*sin(α)^4-22*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^4+2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^4+11*a1^2*b2^4*h*k*sin(α)^4-b1^2*b2^4*h*k*sin(α)^4-a1^2*a2^4*b1^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+a2^6*b1^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+a1^4*a2^2*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-a1^2*a2^4*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-a2^4*b1^2*b2^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-a1^4*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)+a1^2*a2^2*b2^4*cos(α)*sin(α)+a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-2*a2^4*b1^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-a1^2*b2^4*h^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+a2^2*b1^2*h^4*cos(α)*sin(α)-b1^2*b2^2*h^4*cos(α)*sin(α)-5*a1^4*a2^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+a1^2*a2^4*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+5*a1^4*b2^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+11*a1^2*a2^2*h^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)-11*a1^2*b2^2*h^2*k^2*cos(α)*sin(α)+a1^4*a2^2*h*k*sin(α)^2-11*a1^2*a2^4*h*k*sin(α)^2+a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h*k*sin(α)^2+2*a2^4*b1^2*h*k*sin(α)^2-a1^4*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^2+22*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^2-a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^2-2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*k*sin(α)^2-11*a1^2*b2^4*h*k*sin(α)^2-a1^2*a2^2*h^3*k*sin(α)^2-2*a2^2*b1^2*h^3*k*sin(α)^2+a1^2*b2^2*h^3*k*sin(α)^2+2*b1^2*b2^2*h^3*k*sin(α)^2+a1^2*a2^2*h*k^3*sin(α)^2-a1^2*b2^2*h*k^3*sin(α)^2-a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h*k-a2^4*b1^2*h*k+a1^4*b2^2*h*k+a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h*k+a1^2*b1^2*h^3*k+2*a2^2*b1^2*h^3*k-a1^2*b2^2*h^3*k-b1^2*h^5*k+3*a1^4*h*k^3-a1^2*a2^2*h*k^3-3*a1^2*h^3*k^3)*y-2*a1^2*a2^4*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+4*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3-2*a1^2*b2^4*k*cos(α)*sin(α)^3+5*a1^2*a2^4*h*sin(α)^4+a2^4*b1^2*h*sin(α)^4-10*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h*sin(α)^4-2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*sin(α)^4+5*a1^2*b2^4*h*sin(α)^4+b1^2*b2^4*h*sin(α)^4-2*a1^4*a2^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)+2*a1^2*a2^4*k*cos(α)*sin(α)+2*a1^4*b2^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)-2*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)+6*a1^2*a2^2*h^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)-6*a1^2*b2^2*h^2*k*cos(α)*sin(α)+a1^4*a2^2*h*sin(α)^2-5*a1^2*a2^4*h*sin(α)^2+a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h*sin(α)^2-2*a2^4*b1^2*h*sin(α)^2-a1^4*b2^2*h*sin(α)^2+10*a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h*sin(α)^2-a1^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*sin(α)^2+2*a2^2*b1^2*b2^2*h*sin(α)^2-5*a1^2*b2^4*h*sin(α)^2+a1^2*a2^2*h^3*sin(α)^2+2*a2^2*b1^2*h^3*sin(α)^2-a1^2*b2^2*h^3*sin(α)^2-2*b1^2*b2^2*h^3*sin(α)^2+a1^2*a2^2*h*k^2*sin(α)^2-a1^2*b2^2*h*k^2*sin(α)^2-a1^2*a2^2*b1^2*h+a2^4*b1^2*h+a1^4*b2^2*h-a1^2*a2^2*b2^2*h+a1^2*b1^2*h^3-2*a2^2*b1^2*h^3+a1^2*b2^2*h^3+b1^2*h^5+a1^4*h*k^2-a1^2*a2^2*h*k^2-3*a1^2*h^3*k^2=0
```

Comment: amazing but not sure to understand what is M and how do you compute the intersection points of the duals?

Comment: Ok  I think I understand how do you get the intersection points: you "just" solved manually the equation system of the 2 dual conics. But let say this equation is more complexe (with an x*y element for instance). Actually I'm looking for a method to get the intersections points "automatically" from the 2 duals conics equations. Something that I could implement in my software.

Comment: @MohG Can you farm out the calculation to a CAS? Then that’s easy. The general solution to the form in my comment (with five parameters for each ellipse) to the question ran for a looong time without producing a solution like the one you seek.

Comment: Nope. I would like to find  a general solution without any expensive numerical computation. A solution has been posted here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65260321/finding-inner-common-tangent-to-a-pair-of-conics/65554671#65554671] in python but I can’t make it work because not fully understood. Did you check?

Comment: @MohG CASs are symbolic, which is better than numeric for conics. Also the CAS solution I alluded to in the previous comment would be easy to program (substitute the parameters) alas it takes way long to run with ten of these. If you have more information, it could lighten the computation, though.

Comment: @MohG [The geogebra solution](https://www.geogebra.org/m/fwcu6qwm) to one ellipse in standard form.

Comment: SUper thanks for your help @Jan-Magnus, the solution of Futurologist is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the ellipses

$$
\cases{
36x^2 + 9y^2 - 324=0\\
4x^2 + y^2 - 56x - 6y + 201=0
}
$$

and a generic line given by $y =  mx + n$  if the ellipses are tangent to the line, then after substitution, the resulting polynomials in $x$  verify for all $x$:

$$
\cases{
36x^2 + 9(mx+n)^2 - 324=c_1(x-x_1)^2\\
4x^2 + (mx +n)^2 - 56x - 6(mx+n) + 201=c_2(x-x_2)^2
}
$$

which gives us the equations

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}
 9 n^2-c_1 x_1^2-324 =0\\
 2 c_1 x_1+18 m n =0\\
 9 m^2+36 -c_1=0\\
n^2-6 n+201 -c_2 x_2^2=0 \\
 2 c_2 x_2+2 m n-6 m-56=0 \\
 m^2+4-c_2=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Eliminating $\{c_1,c_2,x_1,x_2\}$ we arrive at

$$
\cases{
 126075 - 7380 n - 5234 n^2 + 164 n^3 + 55 n^4=0\\
m = \frac{1}{6216}(14349 + 1435 n - 329 n^2 - 55 n^3)
}
$$

and after solving we get

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
m & n \\
 \frac{1}{15} \left(7+2 \sqrt{21}\right) & -\frac{1}{5} \left(2+7 \sqrt{21}\right) \\
 \frac{1}{15} \left(7-2 \sqrt{21}\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(7 \sqrt{21}-2\right) \\
 \frac{1}{33} \left(21+4 \sqrt{141}\right) & -\frac{1}{11} \left(12+7 \sqrt{141}\right) \\
 \frac{1}{33} \left(21-4 \sqrt{141}\right) & \frac{1}{11} \left(7 \sqrt{141}-12\right) \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

[image]