# Merging two line equations having similar angle into a new one

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-programming, problem-solving

I would like to merge two lines having a `y = mx + b` equation with very close angles. I am simply comparing their angle difference, then I create a new line passing through the middle of these by calculating their m and b average.

This method succeeds when the algorithm encounters two lines with positive values.

[image]

The segment on the right has it's `m` variable set to `0.034`, and `b` variable set to `109.49`.
The segment on the left has it's `m` variable set to `0.017`, and `b` variable set to `128.72`.

The averaging method gives a result of `m` being `0.026` and `b` with the value of `119.105`.

But I am actually stuck in the case where there are two diagonal lines, where one of them has a negative m variable.

[image]

The segment on the top right has it's `m` variable set to `26.837`, and `b` variable set to `-44172.254`.
The segment on the bottom left has it's `m` variable set to `-19.648`, and `b` variable set to `29264.59`.

The averaging method gives a result of `m` being `3.5945` and `b` with the value of `-7453.8324`.

Is there a more efficient method of solving this problem ?

Comment: $m_1 = tan(\alpha_1)$ and $m_2 = tan(\alpha_2)$. You want to get average of two angles, i.e. $\alpha = (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)/2$, however when you average m's you get $m = (m_1 + m_2)/2 = tan(\alpha) = (tan(\alpha_1)+tan(\alpha_2))/2$. So if you need angle average you need to do: $m = tan(\alpha) = tan((\arctan(m_1) + \arctan(m_2))/2)$. Once you find your new $m$ you adjust your new $b$ so that your new line passes through the intersection of the previous two lines.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2403530/265466) gives a formula for computing the bisectors of a pair of lines. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2405467/265466) explains how to choose the sign to get the acute bisector, which is what you’re looking for. The formulas do involve square roots, but no trig or inverse trig functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It fits perfectly with that I need!